# cache() do not work with collect(), but works with take(...)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to cache a `DataFrame` into Memory. When I use `collect()` after `cache()`, the `DataFrame` never gets cached in Memory. But when I use `take(N)`, the `DataFrame` gets cached in Memory.

I would like to know Why am I not able to cache the `DataFrame` while calling `collect()` ? Given below is the example using both `collect()` & `take()`

**cache() behavior with collect()**

```
scala> val hc = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
scala> hc.sql("select * from sparkdb.firsttable").cache()
       res0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: int]
scala> res0.collect()
       res1: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([12], [13], [14], [15])
```

[image]

As you can see, the `DataFrame` is not cached in this case. I was expecting the `DataFrame` to be cached when executing the `action` `collect()`

**cache() behavior with take(N)**

```
scala> res0.take(30)
       res2: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([12], [13], [14], [15])
```

[image]

As you can see, calling `take(N)` does cache the `DataFrame` in Memory.

PS : Given below is some other additional information

**Storage Info after collect()**

```
scala> sc.getRDDStorageInfo
res2: Array[org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo] = Array()
```

**Storage Info after take()**

```
scala> sc.getRDDStorageInfo
       res3: Array[org.apache.spark.storage.RDDInfo] = 
       Array(RDD "HiveTableScan [name#0], (MetastoreRelation sparkdb, 
       firsttable, None), None
" (3) StorageLevel: StorageLevel(false, true, false, true, 1); 
CachedPartitions: 1; TotalPartitions: 1; MemorySize: 256.0 B; 
ExternalBlockStoreSize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 0.0 B)
```

Comment: Can you post your entire code, when you call to cache() ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior...

Comment: @Raj Do you get the same output from `sc.getRDDStorageInfo`?

Comment: I assume this after both `collect` and `take`. How does it change when you start from scratch? I mean `unpersist` -> `cache` -> `collect` -> `RDDStorageInfo` or  `unpersist` -> `cache` -> `take` -> `RDDStorageInfo`

Comment: @zero323, I have update my post with additional information(`RDDStorageInfo` for both `collect()` & `take()`